# Can the Show/Hide timing of the menu bar be adjusted?

Tags: settings, menu-bar, fullscreen, web-browser

When using a **browser** with multiple opened **tabs** in **full screen** mode, the menu bar is constantly blocking my access to the tabs, because my gesture to the tabs area bounces off the top of the screen triggering the Show/Hide behavior. Its harshing my browsing!

The only setting I see is in preferences. 
`System Preferences > General --> Automatically show and hide the menu bar`

Is there a preference file I can edit to change this setting?